# Ni-Fi API: Unauthorized

Tags: api, curl, apache-nifi, unauthorized

When attempting to use the Ni-Fi API, I get an 'Unauthorized' response regardless of the curl request I send.

**If I do not ask for an access token** (a step that many walkthroughs skip), the output of my curl request (`curl -k -XGET https://127.0.0.1:8448/nifi-api/resources`) is a list of control characters (^U^C^C^@^B^BP). Unreadable and not the expected output.

**If I do request an access token**, I am able to get that token. However, when I try the request again (`curl -k -XGET -H 'Authorization: Bearer token-returned' https://127.0.0.1:8448/nifi-api/resources`) I get the following error:

`Unauthorized error="invalid_token", error_description="An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Invalid JWT serialization: Missing dot delimiter(s)", error_uri="https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750#section-3.1"`

**If I remove 'Authorization: Bearer token-returned' from the request**, I don't get control characters anymore, but I just get "Unauthorized" without the details that are output when I use a token.

I used the following request to get the Ni-Fi access token:
`curl -k 'https://127.0.0.1:8448/nifi-api/access/token' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' --data 'username=(Generated Username from nifi-app.log)&password=(Generated Password from nifi-app.log)' --compressed --insecure`

Note: I know that my running Ni-Fi instance can "hear" me because (aside from receiving a token) I can watch the "401" error codes in nifi-request.log every time I try a GET request.

What is happening, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to post a cURL as below

```bash
curl --location 'https://<hostname>/nifi-api/access/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'username=<Username>' \
--data-urlencode 'password=<Password>'
```

> Note: Do replace the values that are enclosed in `<>`